# Swiss ephemeris library wont run at Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I am trying to compile Swiss Ephemeris (ftp://ftp.astro.com/pub/swisseph/swe_unix_src_1.80.00.tar.gz) on a host with Ubuntu on board (uname -a gives "Linux hostname 3.8.0-27-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 9 00:17:05 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"). After compilation (with some insignificant warnings) is produces swetest - testing utility, which stops execution with "Segmentation fault" disgnistics while trying to calculate "True Node" value. So the output looks like:

```
root# ./swetest
Date ?11.11.2012

date (dmy) 11.11.2012 greg.   0:00:00 ET                version 1.80.00
ET: 2456242.50000000000
Epsilon (true)    23°26'10.3185
Nutation           0° 0'12.8789   -0° 0' 5.0637
Sun              228°59'59.3595   -0° 0' 0.4087    0.990046642    1° 0'20.7731
Moon             188°31'57.8543   -3°54'46.3397    0.002459541   14°21'16.6092
Mercury          243° 1'34.8373   -1°40'51.1438    0.725810675   -0°38'50.8096
Venus            196°23'20.1064    1°45'36.9548    1.314241757    1°13'33.8787
Mars             265°24'20.0798   -1° 5'27.6126    2.088236770    0°44'55.7696
Jupiter           74° 7'54.6997   -0°49'34.6905    4.133908104   -0° 6'44.8820
Saturn           214°20'13.6282    2°14'13.1210   10.732657811    0° 7' 6.4939
Uranus             5° 2'49.4996   -0°44'16.5288   19.336198119   -0° 1'31.9324
Neptune          330°21'30.7716   -0°37' 3.2729   29.781739405   -0° 0' 0.6865
Pluto            277°40'41.7136    3°26'39.7902   32.974892720    0° 1'32.2583
mean Node        236°17'52.2579    0° 0' 0.0000    0.002569555   -0° 3'10.7224
Segmentation fault
```

My humble investigation points me to 'swe_calc' call, the main one for calculation of planetary bodies
coordinates calculation. It is documented here: http://www.astro.com/swisseph/swephprg.htm#_Toc365635945

I would appreciate any suggestions or ideas to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.Swiss Ephemeris is an open source C library for astronomical and astrological calculations
of celestial bodies coordinates, speeds, etc.

Comment: "*with some insignificant warnings*" as there were?

Comment: Btw: I would **never** test foreign sources as *root*!

Comment: alk, thanks! It was not root actually )

Answer (score 1):

A quick check on a Debian Stable Linux revealed the `Makefile` misses to `#define` `_GNU_SOURCE`, which leads to a few "*implicit declarations*" and "*assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast*"  which are not "nice" for at least the `strdup()` call if on 64bit.

To fix this modify the `Makefile` as follows.

Changes this line

```
CFLAGS = -g -O9 -Wall -fPIC # for Linux and other gcc systems
```

to become this line:

```
CFLAGS = -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O9 -Wall -fPIC -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99    # for Linux and other gcc systems
```

Comment: alk, thank you for the suggestion! I have followed this, but the story ends with the same Segfault crash. To add: my previsous experience on "FreeBSD 8.x" and "CentOS 5.7 x86_64" was quite smooth.

Comment: @DavidPilgrim: Running it in with gdb would produce backtrace an shows where it crashes. Also those warning you mentioned in your OP might be interesting.